# Matlab: Merge year into interval

Tags: matlab, merge, intervals

I have a vector with decades (note that some decades are deliberately missing:

```
decades = [1910 1920; 1921 1930; 1931 1940; 1951 1960]
```

and a vector with some years (max. 1 per decade) with a piece of information (let's say accidents):

```
years = [1916 35; 1923 77; 1939 28; 1941 40; 1951 32]
```

Is there a way to combine the information to the decades, other than using a loop?

```
result = [1910 1920 35; 1921 1930 77; 1931 1940 28; 1951 1960 32]
```

Comment: What do you want to do if there is more than one row in `years` corresponding to the same decade? Add the accidents?

Comment: Good point, but there shouldn't be more than one year per decade in my dataset. No need to worry about this case.

Comment: @traindriver `decade` and `years` would be sorted always?

Comment: @Divakar yes, both are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @traindriver awesome! :)

Comment: Can a decade have _no_ value in `years`?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, this is possible.

Comment: @traindriver In continuation with the latest query from Luis, so in that case should the `result` include that entry from `decade` with `0` as the third column or just not consider that decade at all in `result`?

Comment: @Divakar A `0` would be better. Thank you for covering both cases, though! :)

Comment: @traindriver Yeah I had to! Can't leave any possibility uncovered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions (taken from OP's comments):

a. There won't be more than one `year` per `decade`.

b. `decade` and `years` are always sorted.

**Code**

```
%// Slightly different inputs to verify the correctness of code across
%//general cases, but within the above mentioned assumptions
decades = [1910 1920; 1921 1930; 1931 1940; 1951 1960; 1971 1980]
years = [1916 35; 1939 28; 1941 40; 1951 32]

cm = bsxfun(@ge,years(:,1),decades(:,1)') & bsxfun(@le,years(:,1),decades(:,2)')
select_years = any(cm,2)
select_decades = any(cm,1)

%// If result is needed such that decades which do not have a entry in
%// years must be logged in with the third column as 0
result = [decades sum(bsxfun(@times,cm,years(:,2)))'] %//'

%// If result is needed such that decades which do not have a entry in
%// years must be skipped
result = [decades(select_decades,:) years(select_years,2)]
```

**Output**

```
decades =
        1910        1920
        1921        1930
        1931        1940
        1951        1960
        1971        1980
years =
        1916          35
        1939          28
        1941          40
        1951          32
result =
        1910        1920          35
        1921        1930           0
        1931        1940          28
        1951        1960          32
        1971        1980           0
result =
        1910        1920          35
        1931        1940          28
        1951        1960          32
```

Comment: This seems to fail when there are empty decades. For example, try `years = [1916 35; 1918 77; 1943 28; 1945 40; 1951 32]`. Not sure if that's a problem, the OP doesn't say

Comment: @LuisMendo let me look into it, thanks on that find!

Comment: @LuisMendo Fixed the `empty-decades` issue. The input you have mentioned here has two entries  in one decade, which OP said won't be the case, so I don't think I need to worry about that. Thanks again really on finding the issue!

Answer (score 2):

This accumulates values if there is more than one per decade. It also handles the case when a decade doesn't have any value.

```
[~, bin] = histc(years(:,1),reshape(decades.',[],1)); %'// find bin of each value
bin = (bin+1)/2; %// non-integers here indicate intervals between decades
bin(mod(bin,1)~=0) = size(decades,1)+1; %// values between decades: move to end
accum = accumarray(bin,years(:,2)); %// accumulate all values from each bin
result = [decades accum(1:end-1)]; %// remove end bin (values between decades)
```

Example with two values in one decade, and zero values in some other decade:

```
decades = [1910 1920; 1921 1930; 1931 1940; 1951 1960];
years = [1916 35; 1918 77; 1939 28; 1941 40; 1951 32];

result =

        1910        1920         112
        1921        1930           0
        1931        1940          28
        1951        1960          32
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decades = [1910 1920; 1921 1930; 1931 1940; 1951 1960]
years = [1916 35; 1923 77; 1939 28; 1951 32]

new_decades_1=repmat(decades(:,1),1,size(decades,1))
new_decades_2=repmat(decades(:,2),1,size(decades,1))
new_years=repmat(years(:,1),1,size(years,1))

cond=(new_decades_1<=new_years') & (new_decades_2>=new_years')
[x,y]=find(cond);

result=[decades,years(x,2)]
```

This however requires that years and decades have the same length.